# Why was my flag for protecting a question declined despite the question becoming protected?

Tags: support

I recently flagged [a question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58127/why-do-humans-suffer-anxiety-when-they-view-trypophobia-trigger-images) for protection. The flag was declined, however, the question became protected. My question is why is this the case? Is this a typical response to flagging for protection?

My flag:

> I think this question should be protected. Besides my answer, both the other answers amount to "Hey, me too!" comments. – James yesterday

The response:

> declined - Protection is generally applied when one or mostly more answers were deleted from a question. I see no reason for protection... Yet

Unfortunately, the response is truncated and "Yet" is the final word. I cannot see the full justification.

An answer to this meta question could give users an insight into how protection is applied, and if/when/how we should be flagging questions for protection.

Comment: I can answer that: I have only seen the flag but not decided due to time reasons. I still found the idea of protecting the question good.

Comment: I see. So somebody else dealt with the flag and left the question unprotected, and you later closed it. I wonder, how often do flags for protecting a question turn up?

Comment: Yep, exactly. This is the first request I remember. Although I usually protect questions, which have two deleted spam or low quality answers. Some questions (especially those who have been featured as "hot network questions" with a lot of views) kind of act as a magnet for low quality answers.

Comment: *Is this a typical response to flagging for protection?*... Not really; that decline message is custom and is the opinion of the mod who dealt with the flag. Regarding how and when to apply protection: it is still quite a murky zone. Protection is basically used to prevent non-trusted users from posting. IMO, it should be used when the question attracts a lot of  sub-standard answers from new users. As Chris pointed out, this happens a lot when a question hits the HNQ list. However, the community should also use downvotes.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Downvotes failed this time. In this case, the answers are devoid of any scientific evidence and rely instead on rationalism (that's being generous. It's substantially speculation in my opinion). Both the answers were from brand new users, and both have positive scores. I doubt this got to the HNQ list, but it has attracted thousands of views in a few days. That damage has been done. Now, should I flag those answers despite them having positive scores, or just let them be?

Comment: @James Post notice has been added in these answers. I personally posted a comment reiterating that we want authoritative answers based on valid references and answers based on "feelings" and personal experiences are not accepted even if the said experience is shared by many people.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thanks. Yes, I think the banner is enough. Plenty of users are asking for references and expansion in the comments so hopefully any reader will understand the answers are incomplete.